# ApplicationBarIconButton throwing AccessViolationException when i try to make any change

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a set of applicationbariconbuttons on one of my xaml page, it looks something like this on the xaml:

```
<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="button1" IconUri="/Images/YourImage.png" Text="Button 1"/>
```

in xaml.cs:

```
button1.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/YourImage2.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

When i add execute the change of iconuri or even text, it throws an AccessViolationException

I wonder what's going on as all over the net, that's the way you do such a simple/straightforward change. And the image file is already changed as "Content", build action as "Do not copy", i've tried all sorts of combination but it's still throwing errors. I've even recreated the whole solution.

But i'm having a problem whereby the xaml doesn't get updated when i make any change, the only way for me to update the app on the device is by deleting and reinstalling.

another strange thing is that, when i run code analysis, i'm getting this:

```
CA0001 Error Running Code Analysis
CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module 'XXX': Could not resolve member reference: 
[Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx::Delay.
[Errors and Warnings] (Global)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the application bar buttons via name.

Something like this should work

```
  // Get the current application bar
  ApplicationBar thebar = this.ApplicationBar as ApplicationBar;

  // You need to know the index of the button in the collection and grab it
  ApplicationBarIconButton thebutton = thebar.Buttons[0] as ApplicationBarIconButton;

   //change the icon image
  thebutton.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/YourImage2.png", UriKind.Relative);
```